# Name of control in routed event

Tags: wpf, vb.net, telerik, radgridview, radcombobox

Isn't there a way to tell what control fired a routed event?  I have a SelectionChangedEvent for use by a combobox on a radgridview.  I want the coding in that event to handle only that combobox and no others.  I tried using e.OriginalSource.Name, ToString, sender.ToString, sender.Name but all return "".  So there's no way to tell what combobox is being processed by the event.

Code to create event:

```
Me.AddHandler(RadComboBox.SelectionChangedEvent, New System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventHandler(AddressOf FinishedEndsChanged))
```

Code inside event:

```
    Private Sub FinishedEndsChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)
        Try
            If dgChosenItems.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
                Dim comboBox As RadComboBox = CType(e.OriginalSource, RadComboBox)

                If comboBox.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim endChosen As String = CStr(comboBox.SelectedValue)
```

Thanks.

Comment: The `sender` parameter will be the combo box that fired the event.  So you can say `If sender Is RadComboBox Then...`.  I assume you're doing this because you're using the same event hander for a bunch of combo boxes but you want a special case for that one. A cleaner solution would be to give it an event handler that is only used for that combo box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the answer here:
[https://www.telerik.com/forums/selection-changed-event-for-gridviewcombobox-column]

I chose to use SelectedValudPath.

Thanks, Patrick, for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

Give your ComboBox a name so you can address it in sourcecode-behind by this unique name. Check

```
If e.OriginalSource == _youridhere_ Then // If sender == ... should work as well 
    // do what you must
```

Not very good style and probably only feasable for one to a few boxes...

Comment: It has a name:  "cboEnds".  But plugging that name in where you suggest gives an "expression expected"  error.

Comment: @EManning I am more familiar with c# - how do you create an expression that asserts if one object is the same as another object in VB? I.e. if `sender` is / == / Equals `cboEnds`

Comment: I believe I found the answer here:  https://www.telerik.com/forums/selection-changed-event-for-gridviewcombobox-column.  I used the SelectedValuePath option.  So far, so good!  Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @EManning consider self-answering and selecting that answer in 2 days. wont give you rep, but might help some later visiter of your problem